# How do I build select into queries in Java

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jdbc

Problem - How do I create a table and insert data based on a query that is generated in Java?

Background - There are a series of tables the queries are based on (20 or so) but there are common operations, like left joining on FKs to the same tables and where clauses that are identical. I'm looking for a clean way to create the 20 queries without rewriting the same joins 20 times.

What I've done so far -

I've built a small application which executes a moderately complex query (sub queries, unions, left joins) and inserts the results of the query into a new table using ;

```
Select col1 as new_col1, col2 as newcol_2 
  into new_table 
from ( .... )
```

I've done this by writing a base SQL file which contains place holders for the column names and new_table which I then replace using a simple string replace in my Java code. I've created about 20 different base SQL files because the from ( .... ) section references different tables and it's a bit too complex to build that part of the query without some libraries.

Comment: There's no single right answer here. In addition to ORM libraries, consider using a template language, like velocity or freemarker to merge your queries and data,

Comment: [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/) provides essentially the same features as jOOQ and is really free

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: That is a very broad interpretation of the term *essentially* and/or *same features*, for instance in the context of this particular feature which QueryDSL certainly doesn't support (and many others) ;)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to wrap Java objects around a DB is to create entity classes and controllers. Netbeans has great tools to help you generate entity's and controller classes. Documentation [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/entity-session.html).

`File->new File`

then search for entity class from database, follow steps in wizard.

After class are made you will want to make JPA controllers

`File-> new File`

then search for JPA controller form entity class.

Select all the entity class and generate! Once you do that I will show you how to use said entity's and controls!

Comment: eclipse has great tools too

Comment: Once I've generated the entities how is the result of the query persisted to the database? This is my concern with the ORM approach (JPA or Hibernate) is that they're not really designed to do things like "select into".